# How to get the checked radio button value outputted to a label

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, findcontrol

I am getting the output of `0` and I don't know what I am doing wrong. I using the findcontrol method to find the IDs within the Gridview and declaring them as radiobuttons, then I am trying to use an if statement to assign the checked radio button a value, then output that value to a label.

**vb code**

```
 Protected Sub btnSubmit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSubmit.Click

    Dim numOutput As Integer

    For Each row As GridViewRow In GridView1.Rows
        Dim qID As Label = row.FindControl("QuestionID")
        Dim rd1 As RadioButton = TryCast(row.FindControl("answer1"), RadioButton)
        Dim rd2 As RadioButton = TryCast(row.FindControl("answer2"), RadioButton)
        Dim rd3 As RadioButton = TryCast(row.FindControl("answer3"), RadioButton)
        Dim rd4 As RadioButton = TryCast(row.FindControl("answer4"), RadioButton)

        If rd1.Checked = True Then
            numOutput = 1
        ElseIf rd2.Checked = True Then
            numOutput = 2
        ElseIf rd3.Checked = True Then
            numOutput = 3
        ElseIf rd4.Checked = True Then
            numOutput = 4
        End If

    Next
    lblOutput.Text = numOutput
End Sub
```

**Source code**

```
 <asp:GridView ShowHeader="false" AutoGenerateColumns="false" ID="GridView1" runat="server" GridLines="None">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField>

                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="QuestionID" Text='<%# Eval("QuestionID")%>' />
                    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="Question" Text='<%# Eval("Question")%>' /><br />
                    <asp:RadioButton GroupName="a" Text='<%# Eval("answer1")%>' runat="server" ID="answer1" /><br />
                    <asp:RadioButton GroupName="a" Text='<%# Eval("answer2")%>' runat="server" ID="answer2" /><br />
                    <asp:RadioButton GroupName="a" Text='<%# Eval("answer3")%>' runat="server" ID="answer3" /><br />                  
                    <asp:RadioButton GroupName="a" Text='<%# Eval("answer4")%>' runat="server" ID="answer4" /><hr />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

        </Columns>

    </asp:GridView>

<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" />
   <asp:Label ID="lblOutput" runat="server" Text="" />
```

Answer (score 0):

## Your bug

I don't know what's wrong with your code because I can't debug your code for see what happens on your VB code. If you don't know how you can debug your code, please watch [this YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C0vDKXIq_9A) about debugging.

---

## My suggestion

I suggest you to place all your check boxes onto a panel and loop over all the items of that control. I go check if each control is a `RadioButton`. if yes, cast that onto a `RadioButton` and check if the `RadioButton` is checked. If yes, **counter** can be display in your label.

The **counter** counts witch `RadioButton` is checked and is also the output you can show on your label. See also code for more information for what I do.

Don't forget to add one to the counter or it will stay on the same value.

Here is the VB code:

```
Dim counter As Integer = 0

For Each contr As Control In pnlAnswers.Controls 'loop over each control on the panel

    If TypeOf contr Is RadioButton Then 'Check if contr is a RadioButton 
        
        RadioButton rdb = CType(contr, RadioButton) 'if yes cast it to a RadioButton

        If rdb.Checked Then 'If checked

            lblOutput.Text = counter.ToString() 'Place the tag value on the output label
            Return

        End If

        counter += 1
    End If
Next
```

Place also your labels outside the panel. Note that it has no impact for the code behind if the labels are inside the panel. The loop will skip them because a label is not a type of a radio button. But it beter that the labels are outside when you add some features to your application.

Here is the ASP code:

```
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="QuestionID" Text='<%# Eval("QuestionID")%>' />
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="Question" Text='<%# Eval("Question")%>' /><br />

<asp:panel ID="pnlAnswers" runat="server">
    <asp:RadioButton GroupName="a" Text='<%# Eval("answer1")%>' runat="server" ID="answer1" /><br />
    <asp:RadioButton GroupName="a" Text='<%# Eval("answer2")%>' runat="server" ID="answer2" /><br />
    <asp:RadioButton GroupName="a" Text='<%# Eval("answer3")%>' runat="server" ID="answer3" /><br />
    <asp:RadioButton GroupName="a" Text='<%# Eval("answer4")%>' runat="server" ID="answer4" />
</asp:panel>
```

**P.S.:** The tags I've added on a previous update aren't necessary now.

---

## Code clean up

I've also removed this line of code:

```
Dim qID As Label = row.FindControl("QuestionID")
```

I can't find any line where you use this line so it's overkill to find your label `QuestionID`.

---

## Notes

It's a long time ago I've used VB.NET and ASP.NET web forms so please comment me if the code is not working.

**#SOreadytohelp**

Comment: Hi, the reason I am trying to assign them values 1-4 is because down the line I will be checking the values against values within my database. I have a CorrectAns fieild which are integer values ranging from 1-4. So you see why I want the radiobuttons having values 1-4 so I can match them against the  correct answer data in the database and if the user has selected the correct radiobutton answer I want to output it to a label.

Comment: @SRock2016: well you can make a counter and every time you loop. See my answer for more information. You can see it in a minute.